# 403 Google Translate API Daily Limit Exceeded

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-translate

I am new to using the Google Translate API. I only got 1 request to go through, then it started failing. I am getting the error that the daily limit has been exceeded. My billing account is linked and enabled. The api is enabled. The access token has been created and that is working via the test cURL request.

Here is my code for my test method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;

class GoogleTranslateController extends Controller
{

    # Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
    private $projectId = 'my_project_id';

    public function translate()
    {

  //$content, $targetLanguage
    # Instantiates a client
            $translate = new TranslateClient([
                'projectId' => $this->projectId
            ]);

    # The text to translate
            $text = 'Hello, world!';
    # The target language
            $target = 'es';

    # Translates some text into Russian
            $translation = $translate->translate($text, [
                'target' => $target
            ]);

        return $translation['text'];
    }


}
```

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: I have a route that calls that when I hit the endpoint. Route::get('get/translate','GoogleTranslateController@translate'); So right now I am testing with http://localhost:8000/get/translate to get a test output

Answer (score 0):

After trying it today, the api works. I don't know if there was a time delay from activation or not. I have had this issue before with other Google Api's.